# Transfer learning using saved bottleneck values (inference with full model)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I'm using lastest Keras with tensorflow backend.

I'm not quite sure the correct way to put together the full model for *inference*, if I used a smaller version of my model for training on bottleneck values.

```
# Save  bottleneck values

from keras.applications.xception import Xception
base_model = Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
prediction =  base_model.predict(x)
** SAVE bottleneck data***
```

Now  let's say my full model looks something like this:

```
base_model = Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)
```

but to speed up training, I wanted to bypass the earlier layers by loading bottleneck values; so I create a smaller model (including only the new layers). I then train and save the model.

```
bottleneck_input = Input(shape = bottleneck_shape)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D() (bottleneck_input)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(input= bottleneck_input, output=predictions)
save_full_model() #save model
```

after training this smaller model, I want to run inference on the full model. So I need to put together the base model and the smaller model. Not sure what is the best way to to do this.

```
base_model = Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
#x = base_model.output

loaded_model = load_model() # load bottleneck model

#now to combine both models (something like this?)
Model(inputs = base_model.inputs, outputs = loaded_model.outputs)
```

What is the proper way to put together the model for inference?
I don't know if there is a way to use my full-model for training, and just start from the bottleneck layers for training and input layer for inference.  (Please not this is not the same as freeze layers, which just freezes the weights (weights won't be updated), but still calculates each data point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every model is a layer with extra properties such as loss function etc. So you can use them like a layer in the functional API. In your case it could look like:

```
input = Input(...)
base_model = Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
# Apply model to input like layer
base_output = base_model(input)
loaded_model = load_model()
# Now the bottleneck model
out = loaded_model(base_output)
final_model = Model(input, out) # New computation graph
```